# Form action field unable to upload and move to new page together

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, mysqli

EDITED: Answered by @James solution is bolded in the code below.
Thanks again @James.

---

I have a form(HTML) which has a text field and upload a file to database. 
Before I was using

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data"></pre>
```

It was working fine, now I want the page to submit the entries to database and display a different page so I tried this

```
    <form action="page3.php"......>, but didn't worked.
```

However when I click Submit button it make the entry for text field in database but does not upload the file to database. 
What I want it to do is: when I click submit button, text field gets entered in database, file gets uploaded to database folder(and my program make its path entry to database), and new page which is loaded for the user to see.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
my php code

```
    <?php

    //ob_start();
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db_name="newrep";
    $table_name="members";

    $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','newrep');
    if(!$conn){
        die("cannot connect.");
    }
    //else if(!mysql_select_db($db_name)){
      //  die(" cannot select database.");
    //}

    session_start();
    use foundationphp\UploadFile;
    echo "Session value: ".$_SESSION['texas'];
    $currentuser=$_SESSION['texas'];
     echo $currentuser;
     $current_year=date("Y");

     //code for upload starts here
    require_once 'src/foundationphp/UploadFile.php';
    if (!isset($_SESSION['maxfiles'])) {
    $_SESSION['maxfiles'] = ini_get('max_file_uploads');
    $_SESSION['postmax'] = UploadFile::convertToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    $_SESSION['displaymax'] = UploadFile::convertFromBytes($_SESSION['postmax']);
    }
    $max = 2048 * 1024;
    $result = array();
    //upload code ended above
    if(!isset($_SESSION['texas'])) 
    {
      header('Location:login_page.php');
      exit();
   }
   else {
    if(isset($_POST['title'])){
      echo "reaching the else";
      if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
      //upload in POST is for upload
        print_r($_FILES);
      $destination = __DIR__ . '/uploaded/'; //for upload
      //upload code try and catch
      try {
      $upload = new UploadFile($destination);
      $upload->setMaxSize($max);
      //$upload->allowAllTypes();
      $upload->upload();
      $result = $upload->getMessages();
        } 
      catch (Exception $e) {
        $result[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
      } 
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($result || $error){ 
    //<ul class="result">
    if ($error){
    echo "{$error['message']}"; }
    if ($result) {
    foreach ($result as $message) {
    echo "<li>$message</li>";}}}

    $file_path_variable= $destination.$_SESSION['current_filename'];
    echo $file_path_variable;

    $title=$_POST['title'];

    $query="INSERT INTO proposal(title_prop, userName_prop,whitepaper_prop,year_prop) VALUES('$title','$currentuser','$file_path_variable','$current_year')";

    $result_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

   echo "      in elseif         ";
    if(!$result_query){
      echo " cannot insert ";
    }
    else {
**header('Location: page3.php');
exit();**
      //echo "successful entry ";
    }
   }
    //ob_end_flush();    
 ?>
```

HTML code here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Online Application</title>
  <!--  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<head><script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script> </head>
<body>
    <div id="O_o"><br><h4>Texas State University</h4></div>
<div id="wrapper">
      <form action=**"<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"** method="POST" id="whitepaper" name="whitepaper" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<legend><h5><b>Online Application</b></h5></legend>

          <h4 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference"><b>Proposal Whitepaper</b></h4>

<fieldset>
<center>
<div class="form-group">
 <?php echo "Year of Proposal: $current_year";?><br> 
<label class="label_title control-label" for="title">Submit Title of your proposal:</label>
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_title form-control" >
<p class="help-block">All fields are required.</p><!--
<button type="submit" id="submit_button" name="btn-primary" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit Title </button>-->
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="label_whitepaper control-label" for="file">Upload the whitepaper of your proposal here: <br>Only .docx , .doc and .pdf format extensions are permitted.</label>

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max;?>">

<p><input type="file" id="filename" name="filename[]" title="Browse for whitepaper" class="btn-primary" multiple
  data-maxfiles="<?php echo $_SESSION['maxfiles'];?>"
  data-postmax="<?php echo $_SESSION['postmax'];?>"
  data-displaymax="<?php echo $_SESSION['displaymax'];?>"></p>

File should be no more than <?php echo UploadFile::convertFromBytes($max);?>.<br>
<!--<p><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File" class="btn-primary">-->
<button id="submit" name="upload" class="btn-primary" >Submit and continue</button>
</div>

</center>


</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<script src="js/checkmultiple.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="prettify.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php } 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: None of your code came through.

Comment: Just a guess, you have an error on line 37

Comment: Just edited the post please review it. thanks

Comment: Can anyone help please.. any suggestions?

Comment: Also, if you put the entire form on here, from beginning form tag to end form tag, it will be easier to find issues.

Comment: Just updated my code.

Comment: And you said you are not seeing any of the `echo` messages that you have above?  Is the page fully loading after it posts, or do you just get a white screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form tag:

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method="POST" name="form1" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Without it, attachments cannot be sent through the form.

**Update**

Try the below code.  I fixed some HTML errors as well.

```
<?php

    //ob_start();
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db_name="newrep";
    $table_name="members";

    $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','newrep');
    if(!$conn){
        die("cannot connect.");
    }
    //else if(!mysql_select_db($db_name)){
      //  die(" cannot select database.");
    //}

    session_start();
    use foundationphp\UploadFile;
    echo "Session value: ".$_SESSION['texas'];
    $currentuser=$_SESSION['texas'];
    echo $currentuser;
    $current_year=date("Y");

    //code for upload starts here
    require_once 'src/foundationphp/UploadFile.php';
    if (!isset($_SESSION['maxfiles'])) {
        $_SESSION['maxfiles'] = ini_get('max_file_uploads');
        $_SESSION['postmax'] = UploadFile::convertToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
        $_SESSION['displaymax'] = UploadFile::convertFromBytes($_SESSION['postmax']);
    }

    $max = 2048 * 1024;
    $result = array();
    //upload code ended above
    if(!isset($_SESSION['texas'])) 
    {
        header('Location:login_page.php');
        exit();
    }else {
        if(isset($_POST['title'])){
            echo "reaching the else";
            if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
                //upload in POST is for upload
                print_r($_FILES['fieldname']);
                $destination = __DIR__ . '/uploaded/'; //for upload
                //upload code try and catch
                try {
                    $upload = new UploadFile($destination);
                    $upload->setMaxSize($max);
                    //$upload->allowAllTypes();
                    $upload->upload();
                    $result = $upload->getMessages();
                }catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result[] = $e->getMessage();
                }
            } 
            $error = error_get_last();
            if ($result || $error){ 
                //<ul class="result">
                if ($error){
                    echo "{$error['message']}"; }
                if ($result) {
                    foreach ($result as $message) {
                    echo "<li>$message</li>";
                    }
                }
            }

            $file_path_variable= $destination.$_SESSION['current_filename'];
            //echo $file_path_variable;

            $title=$_POST['title'];

            $query="INSERT INTO proposal(title_prop, userName_prop,whitepaper_prop,year_prop) VALUES('$title','$currentuser','$file_path_variable','$current_year')";

            $result_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

            //echo "      in elseif         ";
            if(!$result_query){
                echo " cannot insert ";
            }else {
                header('Location: page3.php');
                exit();
                //echo "successful entry ";
            }
        }
        //ob_end_flush();    
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

                <title>Online Application</title>
                <!--  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
                <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="O_o"><br><h4>Texas State University</h4></div>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <form action="<?php= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" id="whitepaper" name="whitepaper" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend><h5><b>Online Application</b></h5></legend>

                            <h4 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference"><b>Proposal Whitepaper</b></h4>
                            <center>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?php echo "Year of Proposal: $current_year";?><br> 
                                   <label class="label_title control-label" for="title">Submit Title of your proposal:</label>
                                   <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_title form-control" >
                                   <p class="help-block">All fields are required.</p><!--
                                   <button type="submit" id="submit_button" name="btn-primary" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit Title </button>-->
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="label_whitepaper control-label" for="file">Upload the whitepaper of your proposal here: <br>Only .docx , .doc and .pdf format extensions are permitted.</label>

                                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max;?>">

                                    <p><input type="file" id="filename" name="filename[]" title="Browse for whitepaper" class="btn-primary" multiple
                                      data-maxfiles="<?php echo $_SESSION['maxfiles'];?>"
                                      data-postmax="<?php echo $_SESSION['postmax'];?>"
                                      data-displaymax="<?php echo $_SESSION['displaymax'];?>"></p>

                                    File should be no more than <?php echo UploadFile::convertFromBytes($max);?>.<br>
                                    <!--<p><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File" class="btn-primary">-->
                                    <button id="submit" name="upload" class="btn-primary" >Submit and continue</button>
                                </div>
                            </center>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <script src="js/checkmultiple.js"></script>
                <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="prettify.js"></script>
                <script src="bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();
                    });
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
    <? } 
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: I have that in my real code, i just omited it here thought would be obvious.. sorry. My problem is when I submit it doesn't upload the file and move the control to new page for the user.

Comment: Then if you print out `print_r($_FILES['fieldname']);` on the page that processes the upload, what do you get?

Comment: I tried on the same page which has the form tag because it has most of the upload and database entry code. Nothing happens.
seems like the upload doesn't even get initiated because I have echo's all all through my upload code for error checking

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I thought you are pointing to a page other than the one the form is on?  Or do you mean you are now pointing it back to the same page?  Also, can you post your entire form code and your PHP processing code?

Comment: @AryaSingh I see you put `fieldname` in your `print_r` as well.  You needed to replace that with your form's file field name.  However, you can just do `print_r($_FILES);` which I should have said to begin with.

Comment: I just updated my entire php code and html. Sorry I am a newbie.
I was trying to take proposal title (text field) and whitepaper(file type) and make their respective entries in database. which was working fine when I using <?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> in action field of <form> tag. 
However when I change it from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to action="page3.php" the file upload doesn't work.

Comment: No the php i have provided is in the same page as html.
page3.php is the page that I want next after entries are made to databse.

Comment: Then that is your first issue.  If you are pointing the form to `page3.php` but do not have the code to process the form in `page3.php` then nothing will happen with the data.  You first need to process the data, then go to `page3.php` or add the code to process the data to `page3.php`.

Comment: thanks for looking in to it.
However is there no way that I can manage both of these job done with on submit button?

Comment: There is.  I've just updated my code.  But yes, you could have it submit the data to page3.php like you have now and just add the PHP code the page3.php.  Or you can do how I did above and have it submit the data to itself and if successful redirect to page3.php

Comment: Yes. Its perfect, exactly way I wanted. Hey Thanks again.